# How can I run Grid up and running

Tags: java, selenium, junit5, selenium-grid2, selenium-jupiter

Is it possible to run the hub and nodes in Selenium Grid through Java/Selenium code? In an example provided by @Boni Garcia, there is `GridLauncherV3` but this is not working with Selenium-jupiter version 3.2.1. Can you please help?

```
    // Start hub

    GridLauncherV3.main(new String[] { "-role", "hub", "-port", "4444" });

    // Register Chrome in hub
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    GridLauncherV3.main(new String[] { "-role", "node", "-hub",
            "http://localhost:4444/grid/register", "-browser",
            "browserName=chrome", "-port", "5555" });
    '''
```

Comment: I want to run it for cross browser. That means, one test for 3 browsers, primarily for IE, Firefox and Chrome. How can I do that?

Comment: @Boni Garcia, could you please take a look at this question. Is it something you are able to answer? Thanks.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71009889/is-there-a-way-to-call-a-java-method-that-extends-a-webdriver-class?noredirect=1#comment125529022_71009889

Answer (score 1):

This [example](https://github.com/bonigarcia/selenium-jupiter/blob/master/src/test/java/io/github/bonigarcia/seljup/test/advance/RemoteWebDriverJupiterTest.java) is working at the time of this writing, I have just double checked. Just notice it is disabled, an so you need to remove the `@Disabled` annotation to execute it.

Comment: I could do it. However I want to run it for cross browser. That means, one test for 3 browsers, primarily for IE, Firefox and Chrome. How can I do that?